# How can I get Screen Sharing to perform well with heavy updates?

Tags: osx-lion, vnc, latency, screen-sharing

I am using `Screen Sharing` on the Macintosh OS X Lion to view a remote VNC server display.  I have found that when I have a shell in emacs which has tons of text scrolling by, the `Screen Sharing` application starts to behave badly.

The CPU usage of the `Screen Sharing` application goes to around 105% and stays pegged there and the fan starts running on my MacBook Air.  The user input from my side gets held up and not delivered in real time.  Sometimes, if I wait it will eventually quiesce and start reflecting my input such as mouse movements and keyboard input belatedly.  Other times, waiting a very long time, still never reflecting input events again.  In either case, if I quit and restart `Screen Sharing`, it will behave normally until the next run of lots of text scrolling output being produced on the server.

How can I get `Screen Sharing` to behave like a normal application, for example, to how TightVNC behaves on Windows?

Comment: Why not use another VNC client?

Comment: What are the free alternatives on Macintosh, I'm not aware of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive never used it, but [CotVNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) seems to be the popular VNC viewer for Mac.